# Spring Test: Exclude resources from ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm creating a test in order to check mongo integration.

I've added this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And this is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ModelTest {

    private List<Reference> references;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    //...
```

Currently I'm getting an `Failed to load ApplicationContext` caused by it's trying to load some other configuration:

> Invalid bean definition with name 'messageSource' defined in class path resource [cat/gencat/ctti/canigo/arch/core/i18n/config/canigo-core-i18n.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.defaultLanguage' in value "${application.defaultLanguage}";

I don't know if it has something to do with my main java code:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ 
    "classpath:cat/gencat/ctti/canigo/arch/web/rs/config/canigo-web-rs.xml",
    "classpath:cat/gencat/ctti/canigo/arch/core/i18n/config/canigo-core-i18n.xml"
})
```

I only want to test mongodb related code. I don't need other resource are loaded.

Only config class I need to load for this test would be:

@Configuration

```
public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions(){
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();

        converters.add(new ReferenceWriterConverter());

        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've tried with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MongoConfig.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ModelTest {
```

However, related  mongo resources are not loaded. Currently, I'm getting this error:

> UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital.mongo.ModelTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate' available...

**EDIT 2**

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:51)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.CustomizedJUnitCoreRunner.run(CustomizedJUnitCoreRunner.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.JUnitLauncher.execute(JUnitLauncher.java:26)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.JUnitLauncher.main(JUnitLauncher.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoMappingContext' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: customConversions,mongoCustomConversions
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoMappingContext' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: customConversions,mongoCustomConversions
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoMappingContext' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: customConversions,mongoCustomConversions
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: customConversions,mongoCustomConversions
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    ... 70 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot: Unit test and Config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244737/spring-boot-unit-test-and-config-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `SpringBootTest` starts up the Spring container normally, including these resources. You could use profiles for this issue as explained in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html.

So you could for example do:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!test")
@ImportResource({ 
    "classpath:cat/gencat/ctti/canigo/arch/web/rs/config/canigo-web-rs.xml",
    "classpath:cat/gencat/ctti/canigo/arch/core/i18n/config/canigo-core-i18n.xml"
})
```

and set the active profile in the test to "test":

```
@SpringBootTest
ActiveProfiles("test")
```

This way, this configuration class would not be loaded for tests.

Comment: Could you take a look on my approach? See edited post.

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace? Anyway, you should use an embedded mongo for testing, like https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo

Comment: I've just added full stacktrace.

Comment: Ah you need to change the return type of your `Bean` to `MongoCustomConversions` instead of `CustomConversions`, because otherwise Spring also creates a Bean as part of the autoconfiguration process and cannot decide, which one to use.